# Admob Ads are not visible in my app when I install it from play store

Tags: android, google-play, admob, adsense

When I install my app in my device directly through android studio then the app shows ads but when I download the app from play store then ad doesn't shows up. This is my first app and it's been approximately 3-4 days since the app is published.

Answer (score 0):

Before you're app starts showing ads, it needs a number of requests to start filling ads. When your app starts picking up downloads, you will get more requests, and eventually ads will start showing.

You can try and tell your friends to try out the app in order to get more requests and start showing ads.